# C++ как создать массив из объектов разных классов

Tags: c++, массивы, ооп, объекты, vector

Есть код и нужно создать массив указателей на класс

Есть 2 класса tPoint и tTriangle

```
class tPoint
{
protected:
    ../
public:
    tPoint();
    virtual void setX(float x);
    virtual void setY(float y);
    ../
};

class tTriangle : public tPoint
{
private:
    ../
public:
    tTriangle(float R1, float A1, float R2, float A2, float R3, float A3);
    void setV1X(float c, float fi = 0);
    virtual void setV1Y(float c, float fi = 0);
    ../
};
```

Я попробовал сделать так:

```
tPoint* arr[7];
arr[0]= new tTriangle(100, 0, 100, 120, 50, 240);
arr[0]->setV1Y();
```

Но есть проблема с обращением к методам класса tTriangle, при таком обращении доступны лишь методы класса tPoint, то есть я не могу вызвать setV1Y().
Собственно говоря и вопрос, как обратиться с помощью такого массива к методам tTriangle?

Answer (score 1):

Ответ до удивления простой, но нужно просто, чтобы эти методы были внутри класса `tPoint` (причём виртуальные, потому что в противном случае вы вызовете метод класса `tPoint`, а не `tTriangle`.
Можно применить чёрную магию (что я крайне не советую, т.к. это плохой код стайл) скастовать указатель на `tPoint` к указателю на `tTriangle`. Причём лучше это делать с помощью `dynamic_cast`, т.к. `static_cast` скастует даже если под указателем лежит не то, что надо:

```
dynamic_cast<tTriangle*>(arr[0])->set1VY(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

Если функции члены определены(в особенности конструктор, то

```
dynamic_cast<tTriangle*>(arr[0])->setV1Y(...);
```

Ваши идеи не до конца понятны,  но скорее лучше изменить подход. Раз уж вы неуместно сделали виртуальными сеттеры,  так почему не сделать виртуальными в базовом классе те сеттеры, которые возможно вы будете вызывать для каждого tPoint? И можно было оставлять лишь их. А еще лучше  отказаться от виртуальности и в базовом классе в защищенном поле хранить информацию о переданных аргументах в setV1Y.